# how to display a simple popup in daypilot scheduler

Tags: angularjs

i'm beginner in Angular, I want to display a simple popup in daypilot scheduler when on click on Event just to show details.. thanks for helping !

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S7GH5.png)

Answer (score 0):

Simple process!

[example code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fyS6C.png)

As you see, there are two divs. Your event and popup.

I set the 'ng-click' directive to 'event' div to catch click event.

So when **user clicks the 'event', showPopup variable will be set to true**. (default is false)

And 'ng-show' directive, in popup div, will show you popup if showPopup variable is true.

showPopup variable is in **digest cycle** of Angular.

If you use controller, you can access showPopup variable with $scope.showPopup in the controller.

( If you want close the popup when user clicks 'event' again,

change ng-click="showPopup" to ng-click="showPopup = !showPopup" )

---

I'm angular beginner too. please check official docs!

- ngClick, ngShow direcitve: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive